# Modify proof environment: new line before qed square

Tags: environments

I would like to put the QED square at the end of proof on its own line. How can i do that? The qed square should be right aligned and below the last line of the proof.

Comment: What theorem packages are you using (if any)?

Comment: I am using `amsthm`

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Are you sure you want it? If the last line is short, the result will be horrible.